# Can ItemDescriptor be mapped to a view instead of table

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

i have a view and it will be much easier for me to work against a view instead of a table itself. In ATG, can i map an itemdescriptor to a view instead of a table? Can someone provide me with an example?

TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can. It is actually no different to setting up a normal `item-descriptor`. However *most* views are `read-only` so you need to make sure your `item-descriptor` is also `read-only`. This can be achieved by setting the `writable="false"` property on the `item-descriptor` definition. The name of the view simply becomes the name of the `table`.

```
<item-descriptor name="ExampleItemDescriptor" cache-mode="simple" writable="false" query-expire-timeout="60000" item-cache-timeout="60000" item-cache-size="2000" query-cache-size="2000">
    <table name="name_of_view" type="primary" id-column-names="multiple,columns">
        <property name="aproperty" column-name="column" data-type="string" />
    </table>
</item-descriptor>
```